# How to modify phpmyadmin forbidden page?

Tags: phpmyadmin, centos, centos6

Looked around and ain't finding much talk about this at all.

Anyone have an idea how I can change this? For example, a custom created page?

Not sure what directory this might be on.

I am running Centos 6.

Please let me know if I should instead post this over at SuperUser.

Comment: What do you mean by "phpmyadmin forbidden page" exactly? There are several different things what this could mean, and what you are seeing may be the *server's* forbidden page. Can you add some more detail?

Comment: @Pekka What I meant was for all IP's that are not allowed to see my phpmyadmin login page, it shows them a custom error page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom error document by adding the appropriate directives to `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess`

Simply add a directive like this:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/forbidden.html
```

Where the path and filename specify the absolute path in the filesystem of the rror page you want to use. Since it's any normal page file you can use HTML, PHP or whatever to create your page.